# running javascript function inside jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

Is it possible to run javascript functions inside jsp tags? 
I'd like to run a sudden function as many times as there's objects in my ArrayList. Below doesen't work, but I hope it gives an idea of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
    <script>
    function test(){
        alert();
    }
    </scripts>


<% 
ArrayList<Marker> list = new ArrayList<Marker>();

list = (ArrayList<Marker>)request.getAttribute("markers"); 

for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
    %>
        <script>
        <%
        test();
        %>
        </script>
    <%
}
%>
```

Is it possible to do it with something like ?

```
<c:forEach var="name" items="${markers}">
   <%-- call my javascript function --%>

</c:forEach>
```

Comment: you probably mean `test('<%= list.get(i).name %>')`

Comment: yes it can be done but for that you have to include the script tag

Comment: I tried using script tags, but no luck. Can you tell what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Below correction in your code will work fine for you

```
<script>
    function test(){
        alert("Hello"); // added sample text
    }
 </script>


<% 
ArrayList<Marker> list = new ArrayList<Marker>();

list = (ArrayList<Marker>)request.getAttribute("markers"); 

for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
    %>
        <script>
        test(); //No need to put java script code inside scriptlet
        </script>
    <%
}
%>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<% 
ArrayList<Marker> list = new ArrayList<Marker>();

list = (ArrayList<Marker>)request.getAttribute("house"); 

for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
    %>
      <script>
         test('<%= list.get(i).name %>');
      <script>
    <%
}
%>
<script>
    function test(i){
        alert(i);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

By writing your js code within the script tag inside a out.println() has shown below:

```
<% 
    ArrayList<Marker> list = new ArrayList<Marker>();

    list = (ArrayList<Marker>)request.getAttribute("markers"); 

       for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){

              out.println("<script>test();</script>");
  }
%>
```